# What is the exact translation of 'solummodo'?

Tags: vocabulary, new-latin, adverb, spinoza

What is the exact meaning of 'solummodo'? I take it is an adverb, perhaps? Encountered this in new Latin, more precisely in Spinoza's Ethics. It is translated as 'only', but it is not in my dictionary, so I would like to know what the exact meaning is. Thank you.

> ...*quia assueti sunt eas **solummodo** res contemplari quæ a causis externis fiunt*...

Comment: I haven't seen *solummodo* before, but *modo* is an adverb meaning "only" and *sōlus* is an adjective meaning "alone", so my guess would be an intensified version of *modo* ("really only").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find it under the *solus* dictionary entry in [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=solum&la=la#lexicon):

> 2. Strengthened by modo, and joined with it in one word, **sōlummŏdo** (only late Lat., for the true reading, Plin. 34, 8, 19, § 92, is unam tantum, Jan. Detlef.; “whereas tantummodo is class.): de exercitore solummodo Praetor sentit,” Dig. 4, 9, 1, § 2: “pretii solummodo fieri aestimationem,” ib. 9, 2, 23, § 1; 11, 5, 1, § 3; 28, 5, 1, § 1; Quint. Decl. 247; Tert. Res. Carn. 26; Hier. Ep. 12.—

So it means "only", it's just a stronger version of it.